# hdevtools failed to install on 7.8.3 platform

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm so tired of trying to stay current with Haskell. I figured I'd upgrade to 7.8.3 and based on previous experiences, I just blew away the entire 7.6.3  system, including the .cabal folder of course.
I have the sublimehaskell package so needed to reinstall libraries that it needs. When I got to hdevtools, I got the errors

src/Info.hs:130:59:
    Not in scope: data constructor ‘GHC.MatchGroup’
    Perhaps you meant ‘GHC.DocGroup’ (imported from GHC)

src/Info.hs:164:5:
    Not in scope: ‘Pretty.showDocWith’
    Perhaps you meant ‘Pretty.showDoc’ (imported from Pretty)

src/Info.hs:229:12:
    Not in scope:
      type constructor or class ‘PprTyThing.PrintExplicitForalls’

What's a simple programmer to do?

(OS X 10.9.5)

Comment: things like this will happen in lot's of other langs. as well - have a look at the Python2 vs Python3 story

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This Reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/2dckxa/help_noob_attempting_to_build_hdevtools_on/) is on nearly the same subject. In particular the top answer suggests a [GitHub fork of SublimeHaskell](https://github.com/SublimeHaskell/SublimeHaskell) which does not use the "largely abandoned" hdevtools.

Comment: That's very interesting and useful information. The irony is that I used to post my "help" questions on Reddit and it was suggested that it would be better to post them here. Can't win! I'll look into that solution, thank you.

Comment: Both of the answers (this one and the one from Luc below) are very helpful. I'm sorry I can't mark them both correct but as my underlying goal was to get sublimehaskell working again, this is a more "correct" answer for me than the other one.

Answer (score 3):

Newer versions of GHC (7.7 and 7.8) introduced changes to the GHC API, resulting in a break of compatibility with hdevtools 1.0.5. This is referenced on the hdevtools tracker as [issue #24](https://github.com/bitc/hdevtools/issues/24). The typical course of action in this case would be to wait for a new version to come out. Unfortunately in this case, while there seems to be a [fix](https://github.com/bitc/hdevtools/pull/33) around it appears that the maintainer is not available. This leaves you with these choices:

- wait even more
- build a [modified hdevtools](https://github.com/schell/hdevtools/tree/cabal-support-ghc7.8) that incorporates the necessary changes

However this is half of the work, as that would leave you with a working hdevtools when you really want sublimehaskell. Sadly I am not familiar enough with it to give you any hints. Still, once hdevtools is present a configuration system would do well to skip trying to build it. In which case you’re good to go.

Comment: subliemhaskell will work fine without hdevtools - it should be no big deal

Comment: Thank you ---- I don't mind building hdevtools from guthub or ignoring it if sublimehaskell will live without it. Appreciate the answers.